# UITextView replacing next line symbol with HTML <br> tag string

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I would like to get a string from `UITextView` with next line symbols replaced by `"<br>"` string.

I am debugging `textView.text` string and I don't see any `\n` symbols in it.

I've created `UITextView` via Storyboard. I've tried Alt+Return and Control+Return but nothing of this adding `\n` symbol to `textView.text`

So I would like to replace new line character received from text view with `"<br>"` and vice versa convert string which contains `"<br>"` to a string which could be recognised by text view as a string with new line characters.

Comment: Not sure how you are checking for the new lines characters but if there are multiple lines in your textview string they present are for sure. You can simply replace occurrences of `"<br>"` with `"\n"` and vice versa.

Comment: @LeoDabus hm very strange as debugger does not show up \n characters at all.

Comment: For debugging I would suggest before you print replace occurrences of \ with / just to be able to see it in the debugger. This way you can see it printing. It is intentional that you cant see \n in debugger as how would you print on a new line

Comment: the problem is detected in another place. I debugged text view text when I actually get it. I user parse object for my data model and when I set parseObject["paymentInfo"] = paymentInfo somehow "\n" disappeared.